# What does the word 「になあ」mean?

Tags: words, particle-に, colloquial-language, manga, particle-な

Here is a sentence said by a little boy.

ジョー兄いも気の毒**になあ**　見ろよ　目にはいるものといえばつめたい石のかべと鉄ごうしばかりじゃねえか

I would like to know if it is a colloquial form or alternated form from a certain word or it just has specific meaning by itself.

Supposed that it is a combined particle consisting of「に」and emphasizing particle 「なあ」, is the purpose of the word just to emphasizing the word 「気の毒」?

Answer (score 1):

The `に` part is the same `に` as in these set phrases:

```
お大事に
お可哀そうに
お体を大切に
```

They simply are used so much, they have been shortened from the longer forms:

```
お大事に(なさってください)
お可哀そうに(思います)
お体を大切に(してください)
```

`なあ` is just an emphasis like you said.

You can find [お気の毒に](http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%8A%E6%B0%97%E3%81%AE%E6%AF%92%E3%81%AB) in the dictionary since it is so common.